# Redirecting a new TLD to an existing page

Tags: redirects, ranking, top-level-domains

My client recently bought a vanity domain name and wants to redirect all the traffic that hits this url to their existing website that has a page with a very similar name.

They bought `nameofpage.com` and want all the traffic to go to`clientWebsite.com/name-of-page`

I was thinking of adding a `301` to `nameOfPage.com`. Would this be ideal or would a `302`?

My question is how will this impact on the existing ranking of the page and what would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: You would use a 301 redirect. However, what does your client expect from this?? The domain name by itself will not do anything at all.

Comment: @closetnoc I believe its for a campaign they will be running. the current page is nested  e.g. `path/to/page/` so they wanted an easy to access link to include in their campaign to make it easier for users

Comment: OK. I get it now. The 301 redirect will work just fine. The domain name will not help SEO, but should not hurt it either. Just make sure there is a canonical tag on the target page to indicate that it is the original so there is no confusion. You should be fine.

Comment: @closetnoc so the canonical link would be `clientWebsite.com/path/to/page`?
if you could create that as an answer I can mark it correctly :)

Comment: Cheers mate!! Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, a 301 redirect is appropriate. The 302 is temporary and does not yield the same results. A 301 is more traditional and correct.

Adding another domain name normally will not yield any benefit, however, from a marketing standpoint, using it in a marketing campaign makes sense. While as an IT professional, I cannot stand adding another domain name, the marketer in me says YES! Total win!

The only thing I would do from a cautionary standpoint would be to create a canonical link on example.com/path/to/page that points to itself. While there is generally no danger in your scenario, when a page can be found via multiple URLs, it is always wise to chose one as the original and use a canonical tag. In this case, you do not have a choice as to which URL to use.

Here is Google's page on that. There is an example under the heading: Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en